# How to reduce line height inside merged cell using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I filled text inside merged cell using Apache POI. I want to reduce line height inside cell because second text line is not visible fully. I search something like CSS style `line-height` but for excel.

[image]

Comment: Can't you just use one of [Row.setHeight](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#setHeight(short)) or [Row.setHeightInPoints](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#setHeightInPoints(float))?

Comment: Yes, it seems the only way

Comment: Apache POI cannot do what Excel itself cannot do. In Excel you cannot influence the text line leading (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading) somehow. It is dependent of the font and font size which can be influenced of course.